# How to get the background colour of a View

Tags: android, view, colors

How can i get the current colour of a view, if its a solid colour

```
                int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            Drawable background = rootLayer.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
                color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```

This if statement never returns tru

Comment: because your background is not an instance of `ColorDrawable` if you use Color.TRANSPARENT your background is an instance of `int`

Comment: @tyczj yes ok, but if i remove the if statement i get nullpointer

Comment: Because background is null